# Is it possible update Highchart data automatically and make animated effect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm using Highchart inside React application. I want to make animated effect for Highcart.

For instance, it's to show the progress of uploading other data. I pass the progress via `this.props.progress`. However, I cannot pass props to data property in Highchart.

Is it possible to make an animated effect with updating data? What could be the best practice?

Highchart.js

```
class Highchart extends React.Component {
static propTypes = {
data: React.PropTypes.array,
text: React.PropTypes.string,
colors: React.PropTypes.array,
size: React.PropTypes.any,
bgcolor: React.PropTypes.string,
width: React.PropTypes.number
}

constructor (props) {
super(props)

this.state = {
  uuid: uuid()
}
}

componentDidMount () {
Highcharts.chart(this.state.uuid, {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'pie',
    width: this.props.width,
    backgroundColor: this.props.bgcolor
  },
  title: {
    text: this.props.text,
    useHTML: true,
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    floating: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      shadow: false,
      allowPointSelect: false,
      size: '100%',
      dataLabels: { enabled: false }
    },
    series: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: { enabled: false },
  credits: { enabled: false },
  colors:this.props.colors,
  series: [{
    data: this.props.data,
    size: this.props.size,
    innerSize: '90%',
    showInLegend:false,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }]
})
}
render () {
return (
  <div id={this.state.uuid} className='high-chart' />
)
}
}

export default Highchart
```

ProgressMeter.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Highchart from 'components/Highchart'

class ProgressMeter extends React.Component {
static propTypes = {
progress: React.PropTypes.number,
 }

render () {
return (
  <div
    className='signup-percents-meter'
  >
   <DonutChart data={[this.props.progress, 100-this.props.progress]}
   //this code does not work.
      colors={['#ee382a', '#eaeaea']}
      />
  </div>
  )
  }
  }

  export default ProgressMeter
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing only options will not work for Highcharts - those options are used once for generating chart. If you want to change those options you should call [`chart.update`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update) with new options or a more dedicated update e.g. for **series data** you can use [`series.setData`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData).

How others are handling this:

1. Official Highcharts React wrapper [`highcharts-react`](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react) is using `chart.update` - [the relevant code line](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/blob/2928b862a2004bfc76efed736dd11686096cc5da/src/HighchartsReact.js#L24).
2. Third party [`react-highcharts`](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts) is rebuilding Highcharts chart using new options. It's less optimal, but generally a more secure approach for them (it's third party code, so in case of any bugs they need to wait for the bug to be resolved). Relevant code: [call `renderChart` on updates](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts/blob/49a8641c1d57775f337d9c995caa40b4ad9a6ee8/src/chartsFactory.jsx#L43) and [creating the chart in the `renderChart`](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts/blob/49a8641c1d57775f337d9c995caa40b4ad9a6ee8/src/chartsFactory.jsx#L24-L30).
3. Third party [`react-highcharts-wrapper`](https://github.com/beestripes/react-highcharts-wrapper) also rebuilds a chart on update - [here is explained why](https://github.com/beestripes/react-highcharts-wrapper/blob/9cf20989d6a74a9a34d694cd2ecefe80e6685dc7/src/services/chartApi.js#L23-L33).

About animation:

When chart is rebuild (created anew) initial animation runs (unless otherwise specified in [chart's animation option](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.animation)) and for dynamic updates like `chart.update` chart is redrawn with animation enabled by default.